# Selectize Input style in shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I'm trying to customize my `selectize input` in `shiny`. What I have is:

[image]

And what I would like to have is to change colour of selected items like here:

[image]

I've tried to change my `css`, but I've managed to change only this "a" colour by adding:

```
.selectize-input.input-active, .selectize-input.input-active:hover, .selectize-control.multi .selectize-input.focus {border-color: #2196f3 !important;}
.selectize-dropdown .active {background: #2196f3 !important;}
```

I'd like to change also colour of "c" and "b" but I don't know how. Could you help me please?

My code:

`server.R`:

```
library("shiny")

shinyServer(function(input, output){})
```

`ui.R`:

```
library("shiny")

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectizeInput("select", label=NULL,
                           choices=c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                           multiple=TRUE, options=list(placeholder="Wybierz"))),
        mainPanel())
    )
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this working (just after `fluidPage` and before `sidebarLayout`)?

```
tags$head(
  tags$style(HTML("
     .item {
       background: #2196f3 !important;
       color: white !important;
     }
     .selectize-dropdown-content .active {
       background: #2196f3 !important;
       color: white !important;
     }
  "))
),
```

Comment: thanks! That works. Do you know what to add there to change font colour also?

Comment: I've updated it to include also color = white but you can add any valid css color there

Comment: Great! Why is this `!important` needed? Maybe it's basic but I'm quite new to html...