# Selectize Input style in shiny (for two different selectize boxes)

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

recently someone has helped me with this problem: [Selectize Input style in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386534/selectize-input-style-in-shiny/37387118#37387118). Now, I'd like to go further and have another problem.

What I have are two `selectize inputs`. I'd like to change colours of selected items for each of the selector separatly. Here is the picture which clarifies my problem.

What I have:

[image]

And what I'd like to obtain:

[image]

I've tried to change my `css` with different combinations of id's and classes but with no success. Could you help me?

My code:

`server.R`:

```
library("shiny")

shinyServer(function(input, output){})
```

`ui.R`:

```
library("shiny")

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
                        .item {
                        background: #2196f3 !important;
                        }
                        .selectize-dropdown-content .active {
                        background: #2196f3 !important;
                        }
                        "))
        ),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectizeInput("select", label=NULL,
                           choices=c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                           multiple=TRUE, options=list(placeholder="Wybierz")),
            selectizeInput("select2", label=NULL,
                           choices=c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                           multiple=TRUE, options=list(placeholder="Wybierz"))),

        mainPanel())
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like

```
   tags$style(HTML(" .item {
                    background: #2196f3 !important;
                    }

                    #select2 + div> div>.item {
                    background:   #f3217a !important;
                    }
                    .selectize-dropdown-content .active {
                    background: #2196f3 !important;
                    }

                     #select2 + div> div>.selectize-dropdown-content .active {
                    background:   #f3217a !important;
                    }
                    "))
```

in your css

`select2`  will be different from all others "selects"

or define color for each #select

PS you can do it on server side from table using apply and paste ( like here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37299152/5018792) see in update )